# ASP.Net MVC Execution of the command requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is broken

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

Several of our internal apps are MVC3 and all use Ninject.MVC.

We're running into an issue that affects all the tools at one point. First we get the error:

```
Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.
```

Followed by:

```
Execution of the command requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is broken.
```

This can happen at any time when the tool is used. We've updated our ninjects to the latest versions and it helped a LOT, errors have been much more seldom but still happen when the tools are heavily used. I've been simply setting up Ninject.MVC3 via the nuget package manager and registering the proper services to the NinjectWebCommon.cs.

Here's our our controllers, NinjectWebCommon and global.asax are setup, is there something we're doing wrong here?

One we we know for sure will fix this is to simply get rid of Ninject altogether and instantiate our repositories on each controller. But that's not a good solution I'm guessing.

Global.asax (removed some routes):

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Index", // Route name
            "", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

NinjectWebCommon.cs:

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IToolRepository>().To<ToolRepository>();
    }        
}
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IBattleStationRepository _repository;
    private LoginEntities _loginEntities;
    private SpecialLib _speclib;
    private AccessManager _accessManager;


    public HomeController(IBattleStationRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _speclib = new SpecialLib();
        _loginEntities = new LoginEntities();
        _accessManager = new AccessManager();

    }

    public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        var byPassHomePage = false;
        var urlReferrer = HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer;
        var user = _accessManager.GetUserByUserName(User.Identity.Name);
        if (urlReferrer == null)
        {
            byPassHomePage = true;
        }

        if (user.TeamId != null && byPassHomePage == true)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Release", "Release", new { shortTeamName = user.Team.ShortName });
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be better off creating an instance of your `AccessManager` per each controller method, unless other code depends on what happens in the current method. It seems like the most likely problem is that the global objects were GC'd between requests...

Comment: Some tools don't even use the AccessManager and still crash, but that might be worth a try on those that do though!

Comment: If you haven't tried it yet, Glimpse (http://getglimpse.com) might be useful in pinpointing when the objects go out of scope. At the very least, you might see where the exception actually originates from.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this issue occurs very randomly and we have never been able to reproduce it on our development computers. I'll give it a try but I'm gonna have to be extremely lucky to have the tool crash just as I use Glimpse. There's gotta be something else that we're missing.